# phpMyAdmin change storage engine on a constantly updated table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb, myisam

I have a table that is updated about 5-10 times per second.
Now I would like to change storage engine from MyIsam to InnoDB, and I would like to know if it could generate a problem for my users.

I have this doubt because in the Operations tab storage engine is in the same form of the auto increment index. That form will update auto increment too?

Thank you very much and sorry for my bad English

Comment: stop what ever is writing, make a backup and do the change only offline

Comment: You should read this (if you haven't already) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

Comment: If it is a small table, no one will notice.  If it is a large table, it will be locked for long enough to do the `ALTER`.  See this for other potential issues:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: Thanks, finally I did the change, for a large table with more then 1mln of rows it took about 17 seconds to alter it, but no errors was show to the users, I risked, but was an important change to do as fast as possible! Thank you for helping me